# How can i optimize this query without knowing the tables?

Tags: sql, optimization

```
SELECT
    a.eid,
    a.cid,
    b.e_date
FROM RR_CHARITY a
JOIN RR_EVENTS b ON a.eid = b.eid
WHERE a.cid IN (
    SELECT cid 
    FROM RR_CHARITY_TRANSACTIONS
    WHERE `trnDate` <= '2013-01-01 00:00:00'
)
AND a.eid NOT IN(216,217,322);
```

Comment: How could we know, since we don't even know which dbms it is.

Comment: I got sent this as a test for a job application and they didnt supply me a database

Comment: instead of IN use join RR_CHARITY_TRANSACTIONS c  on a.cid=c.cid

Comment: If I had to guess...  where in (subquery) is most likely your issue and where a interview question would focus.  convert that into a join on a.cid = rr_charity_transactions.cid and trndate <='2013-01-01'

Comment: except that an inner join could multiply rows, but IN() will not, so a functionally equivalent alternative is to use EXISTS. Also if this was my question I would expect the dbms type to be identified as there is a syntax clue (i.e. the backticks suggest MySQL) . The predicate `trnDate <= '2013-01-01 00:00:00'` might involve a implicit type conversion so it should be questioned